# Spring Boot Application failed to start because of missing bean

Tags: java, spring-boot

**How I "solved" it:**
The initial problem was that I forgot to change the package name in the main class that launches the application:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.sda.VictorLiviu.ecommerce.jparepository"})
```

After that I just instanced itemMapper as a normal class in ItemService like this:

```
ItemMapper itemMapper = new ItemMapper();
```

and than used its toEntity method as:

```
itemMapper.toEntity();
```

**. . . . . . . . . . . .**

My Spring Boot app says it doesn't have a Bean class which it clearly has. I will post the Pom, service and repository. I want to point out that I have exactly the same class and repository for UserService and OrderService and they don't give any error, the only difference is the @Transactional and I removed it and got the same error.Any suggestions are welcomed!

**The Error:**

```
Description:

Field repository in com.sda.VictorLiviu.ecommerce.service.ItemService required a bean of type 'com.sda.VictorLiviu.ecommerce.JpaRepository.ItemRepository' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.sda.VictorLiviu.ecommerce.JpaRepository.ItemRepository' in your configuration.
```

**POM XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.sda.VictorLiviu</groupId>
    <artifactId>e-commerce</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>e-commerce</name>
    <description>E-commerce website Final Project sda</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**ItemService class**

```
    package com.sda.VictorLiviu.ecommerce.service;

import com.sda.VictorLiviu.ecommerce.DtoMapper.ItemMapper;
import com.sda.VictorLiviu.ecommerce.JpaRepository.ItemRepository;
import com.sda.VictorLiviu.ecommerce.exceptions.ItemNotFoundException;
import com.sda.VictorLiviu.ecommerce.model.Item;
import com.sda.VictorLiviu.ecommerce.dto.ItemDto;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@Transactional
@Service
public class ItemService {

    @Autowired
    ItemRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    ItemMapper itemMapper;

    public void add(ItemDto dto) {
        repository.save(itemMapper.toEntity(dto));
    }

    public Item delete(Long id) {
        repository.deleteById(id);
        return null;
    }

    public List<Item> getItems() {
        return repository.findAll();
    }

    public Item getItemById(Long id) {
        Optional<Item> optionalItem = repository.findById(id);
        return optionalItem.orElseThrow( () -> new ItemNotFoundException("Couldn't find the specific item!"));
    }
}
```

**Repository**

```
package com.sda.VictorLiviu.ecommerce.JpaRepository;

import com.sda.VictorLiviu.ecommerce.model.Item;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface ItemRepository extends JpaRepository<Item, Long> {
}
```

**Item Class**

```
package com.sda.VictorLiviu.ecommerce.model;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="item")
public class Item {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "item_seq_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "item_seq_gen", sequenceName = "item_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "price")
    private double price;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "category")
    private String category;

    @Column(name = "quantity")
    private int quantity;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }
}
```

**ItemDto Class**

```
package com.sda.VictorLiviu.ecommerce.dto;

public class ItemDto {

    private Long id;
    private double price;
    private String name;
    private String category;
    private int quantity;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }
}
```

**Application.properties**

```
logging.level.org.springframework=info

jwt.signing.key.secret=mySecret
jwt.get.token.uri=/authenticate
jwt.refresh.token.uri=/refresh
jwt.http.request.header=Authorization
jwt.token.expiration.in.seconds=604800

spring.jpa..show-sql=true
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
```

**!!!!!!**
[Image with my packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPcIa.png)

Comment: Show the bean class too

Comment: @Repository is not required .

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I have an ItemDto and an Item class. ItemDto is a simple class with getters, setters and default constructor while Item has needed annotations such as Id, GeneratedValue, in order to create the table when I run the app. Which one is the bean?

Comment: Beans should have `@component` annotation

Comment: I think the problem might be in the package where you hold your repository

Check your packages because currently it is 'package com.sda.VictorLiviu.ecommerce.JpaRepository'

Comment: @S.Tushinov I have different packages in ecommerce for different classes such as repository package, dto package, model package, controller package. What would be the problem? I checked that spring asked in the error log exactly for the path I had for those repositories

Comment: @VictorV what is the package in which you keep your 'ItemRepository ' class ? Or in other words do you really have a package called **JpaRepository**

Comment: @S.Tushinov at the bottom of my post I have added an imgur link with my packages. I will re-edit the whole post after I find the sollution because it is a bit messy now.

Comment: can you try using constructor injection instead of field injection? I'm curious if that will change anything. Also, I would recommend going away from using capital letters in package names.

Comment: You could also try deleting the @Repository annotation from `ItemRepository` as it shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Please post the full `pom.xml`, `application.properties`. Also put `@Table` annotation in the `Item` class and try it.

Comment: Updated pom.xml (posted full) and also posted application.properties and inserted Table annotanion in Item class, still doesn't work. I will talk to someone I know in around 7 hours and I post the sollution if we find any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to turn on jpa repositories processing.

To do this, annotate your application with `@EnableJpaRepositories`

Comment: Thank you! I made a new packages some time ago and forgot to modify it in that annotation. Now the error is about my itemDtoMapper, but I will figure it out in a few hours when I meet someone and I will update the post

Comment: @Antonniossss that solves a part of it, the problem is that the app won't start because of a missing bean. Now its another bean that it says its missing. After I fix it I will post the solution and declare it solved. I think its because I went from CRUD Repository to JPA Repository and messed up the project a bit. I will refactor it with my trainer and post solution

Comment: Seems like a different problem.